# ASP.NET Core 2.1: Navigating back to a page after an HTTP POST fails validation displays a browser error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

**Problem:**

Using an **ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC** project, I'm receiving the following browser error message after using the browser back button to return to a form, where the form POST failed server-side validation:

Error message in Firefox:

> Document Expired
>
> This document is no longer available.
>
> The requested document is not available in Firefox’s cache.
>
> - As a security precaution, Firefox does not automatically re-request sensitive documents.
> - Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website.

Error message in Chrome:

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
>   will repeat any action this page previously performed.
>
> Press the reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>
> ERR_CACHE_MISS

Steps to reproduce:

1. Submit an HTML form post, where server-side validation fails
2. navigating to a different URL
3. click the browser back button to return to the page with the form

**Notes:**

It appears to be related to Response caching (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-2.1) being disabled for the Antiforgery system.

> The Antiforgery system for generating secure tokens to prevent
>   Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks sets the Cache-Control and
>   Pragma headers to no-cache so that responses aren't cached. For
>   information on how to disable antiforgery tokens for HTML form
>   elements, see ASP.NET Core antiforgery configuration.

Which I can confirm, if you remove `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` from being included in the HTML form, the browser error message goes away.

This was not an issue in **ASP.NET MVC5** using the `AntiForgeryToken`.

**Question:**

In **ASP.NET Core 2.1**, has anyone found a way to continue to use the Antiforgery system and prevent this browser error message from being displayed when the browser back button is used?

Here's my POST action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ActionName("Contact-Form")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ContactForm(ContactFormViewModel cfvm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // << Handling of the form submit code here >>

            TempData["Success"] = string.Format("Your contact request was submitted successfully!");

            return RedirectToAction("Contact-Form-Success");
        }

        TempData["Error"] = "The form did not submit successfully. Please verify that all of the required fields are filled.";
        return View();
    }
```

**Update:**

I posted the question on the ASP.NET Core Docs:
https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/7590

Comment: "was not an issue in ASP.NET MVC5 using the AntiForgeryToken", "has anyone found a way to continue to use the Antiforgery system and prevent this browser error message"  Well which is it? Do you mean that this isn't an issue in the framework, or your issue isn't caused by antiforgery

Comment: Antiforgery didn't cause this issue in `ASP.NET MVC5`, but it is now causing an issue in `ASP.NET Core 2.1`. I'm migrating an MVC5 project to Core 2.1, that's why I mentioned the older framework.

Comment: I think he is saying it’s a new issue in .Net Core when you click the back button, although I think it make sense that error comes up for security reasons in case they resubmit form or meddle with ViewState of the page.. You just need to present it in a polite way with custom error page.

Comment: @numbtongue how are other websites able to avoid this though, without a custom error page? I don't see any major websites having this problem. For example, if you submit an invalid login to ASP.NET (https://login.asp.net/account/login), then go to a different page, and then browser back, it doesn't show the browser error message there.

Comment: If it’s a single page site they can manage browser history in such a way that you aren’t really leaving the page, but good question may be someone can answer..

Comment: Is there a reason you're not passing the ContactFormViewModel back to the view after it fails validation? If you do that, the user won't have to use the back button to try to get back to their posted values...

Comment: @G_P Returning the view model hasn't made a difference. The issue is happening after that... For example, 1) Submit invalid form. 2) View is returned w/ validation errors. 3) Go to another webpage 4) Hit browser back button 5) Receive the browser error message.

Comment: I believe the issue does have to do with the `return View()` after it fails validation, but I'm not sure what to return instead.

Comment: What is the Cache-Control for posted form. Plus, this is expected behaviour, as post items are not to be stored by browser. POST is used for sending sensitive information and by default it's not cached. What Adam Vincent suggested is how it's take care of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a not a language specific issue. This is a browser behavior. To say this was 'not an issue with ASP.NET MVC 5' is incorrect.

Solutions: 
A common method of solving this is the [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) which has been around since 1995.

An implementation of this for ASP.NET Core, using `TempData` can be found [here](https://andrewlock.net/post-redirect-get-using-tempdata-in-asp-net-core/)

And I think that this [link](http://piotrgankiewicz.com/2016/04/25/postredirectget-with-new-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) would be most helpful for you, since it demonstrates a method implemented in both MVC 5 and MVC 6.

I hope this helps!

I will try and update this post soon with a sample based on a razor-page starter project, time permitting.

Comment: My issue isn't with Model State and the "Confirm Form Resubmission" popup. The browser error I'm experiencing is different and I believe stems from the `Antiforgery` tokens not being cached. Your PRG answer may circumvent this browser error from occurring (since it's doing a fresh GET), but it's not solving the underlying issue. If you can reproduce the browser cache error in MVC5 let me know, but I am only experiencing it since I upgraded to Core 2.1.

Comment: Fair enough. ^^

Comment: Antiforgery tokens should not be cached. A new submission should require a new token. The error is precisely what you *should* see. Follow the PRG pattern as this answer suggests.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisPratt for clarifying about the Antiforgery tokens. It threw me off because they used to be cached in MVC5. Sorry @AdamVincent for questioning your answer. Going to mark this as correct. So the ASP.NET Core 1.0 article you linked about the `TempData` implementation using the ModelState helpers, is that what you would still use in Core 2.1?

Comment: @Wellspring I believe in questioning everything! I take zero offense. I took a look at the article, and implemented it myself. I admit, I do not like the solution, however it is by far the most thoughtful and deliberate solution I could find. I will back you on the issue you opened on github.com. I think asp.net core team can improve the quality of life for developers for such a common pattern that has been around for a long time.

Comment: Hello, I did not realize before that exist something like PRG. The cms I worked on did it in the background in such a magical way that I never thought about it.

Now I'm working on my own small project. And I admit that I can't find any tutorial that would do it well. Why?
I find such with `Sessions` and` TempData`, but at the same time I found comments that basing logic on the two above solution is not safe and can be broken in many ways.

in which case HOW DO IT CORRECT?

Comment: I recommend posting a new question that references this one, with the sources that say PRG with `Session` or `TempData` is not safe.  I do not believe this is an unsafe method.

Comment: is there a wok around for webforms??